# An animated movie set in a post-apocalyptic future where the main girl has to collect a last spirit

Tags: final-fantasy

I remember watching a movie between the years 2007 and 2011. I am pretty sure it was an anime because it was animated.

I remember a futuristic setting with the planet earth in ruins. The main character was a girl and I think I remember deaths (as in people died) :3 but it couldn't have been anything extreme since I was around 11-14 years old and had never watched anime at that point and would have been turned off by that.

I remember something about a last plant or a spirit that the main character had to collect and maybe the earth having radiation or disease that needed her to wear a special suit, and I also remember her having to go through a test when she got back to base which was some ship to test her for this disease or thing.

I also remember a guy failing this test and some people at the end trying to get to a vehicle like a truck with an open top but that is about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "had death" do you mean that death was a character (like the Grim Reaper), or that people were killed in it?

Comment: As in people died , made an edit

Comment: Does that sound like [*Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy:_The_Spirits_Within) to anyone?

Comment: I had the feeling it was 3d but I thought to myself surely not

Comment: Thank you very much, so you just have to submit it as an answer now for me to like it or whatever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Final Fantasy: The Spirits Within](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy:_The_Spirits_Within)

[image: Final Fantasy theatrical release poster]

> A planet is overrun by a mysterious group of creatures that infect and destroy all life on Earth. Only the determination of a single woman to find a cure will prevent the world from slowly being eaten away. Yet there are those from within who are impatient for results and will do anything to win this war.